# prove or show that

Tags: real-analysis

If $x,y \in\mathbb  R$ with $x < y$, 
show that $x \leq ty+(1-t)x \leq y$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

I have so far is:

any point in ( x , y ) can be given by x + multiple of [ y - x ] if the multiple is

in ( 0 , 1 )..sorry got the wrong one

Comment: Way too complicated. You don't need an $\varepsilon$ proof here! If $x\lt y$ and $t\ge0$ then $tx\le ty$, so $x=tx+(1-t)x\le ty+(1-t)x.$

Comment: What does that stuff you wrote **have to do with the question?** Where did $a_n$ and $b_n$ come from? What happened to $x,y$ and $t$? Did you accidentally copy your answer to **some other problem??**

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have $a\le b$ if and only if $b-a\ge 0$.